# abaqus error when job is created through python script due to a not defined job type name

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm trying to create Abaqus jobs through a python script. Problem is, Abaqus is refusing to detect the job type. it keeps returning this

NameError: name 'ANALYSIS' is not defined

It creates the job fine without the type defined, but it won't accept any type.
These are the modules I imported

```
import section
import regionToolset
import displayGroupMdbToolset as dgm
import part
import material
import assembly
import step
import interaction
import load
import mesh
import optimization
import job
import sketch
import visualization
import xyPlot
import displayGroupOdbToolset as dgo
import connectorBehavior
import SymbolicConstant
import abaqusConstants
```

And this is the actual command I'm using

```
p1 = mdb.models[n].rootAssembly
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=p1)
job=mdb.Job(name=n, model=n, description='', type=ANALYSIS, atTime=None, waitMinutes=0, waitHours=0, queue=None, memory=90,memoryUnits=PERCENTAGE, getMemoryFromAnalysis=True,explicitPrecision=SINGLE, nodalOutputPrecision=SINGLE, echoPrint=OFF, modelPrint=OFF, contactPrint=OFF, historyPrint=OFF,userSubroutine='', scratch='', resultsFormat=ODB,numThreadsPerMpiProcess=1, multiprocessingMode=DEFAULT, numCpus=4,numDomains=4, numGPUs=0)
```

I tried multiple job types.
I tried creating the commend by recording a macro script and then running that exact macro but it still won't work.
The only way I was able to create the job is without the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, all the constants such as `ANALYSIS`, etc., are defined in the `abaqusConstants` Abaqus module. 
You have imported the `abaqusConstants` module, however, you are using the constants defined in that module. To use the constants from that module, you have use reference to that module. Simply put, you have use it as follows:

```
import abaqusConstants

# Use the constant from abaqusConstants using .(dot) notation
ana_type = abaqusConstants.ANALYSIS
```

**OR**
You can use the simpler way as:

```
from abaqusConstants import *

# No need to give the reference to the module using .(dot) notation
# as you have directly imported all the constants in the current namespace directly
ana_type = ANALYSIS
```

This option is, as you can see, easy to use as we have sometime very long Abaqus API commands. As in your code also, you have used many constants, such as `ANALYSIS`,  `PERCENTAGE`, `SINGLE`, `OFF`, etc. So, if you use reference (1st option), the command will be much longer. 
You can modify your code as below (change is only in the import statements):

```
from caeModules import *
import regionToolset
import displayGroupMdbToolset as dgm
import xyPlot
import displayGroupOdbToolset as dgo
from abaqusConstants import *

p1 = mdb.models[n].rootAssembly
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=p1)
job=mdb.Job(name=n, model=n, description='', type=ANALYSIS, atTime=None,
            waitMinutes=0, waitHours=0, queue=None, memory=90,memoryUnits=PERCENTAGE,
            getMemoryFromAnalysis=True, explicitPrecision=SINGLE, nodalOutputPrecision=SINGLE,
            echoPrint=OFF, modelPrint=OFF, contactPrint=OFF, historyPrint=OFF,
            userSubroutine='', scratch='', resultsFormat=ODB, numThreadsPerMpiProcess=1,
            multiprocessingMode=DEFAULT, numCpus=4, numDomains=4, numGPUs=0)
```

Comment: Yep. Works perfect. I still don't know why it behaves like this though. A macro from Abaqus does not even import abaqusConstants at all. Thanks though!

Comment: Some constants which are module specific (Part, Assembly, etc.,) are stored in those modules as well. For ex. `THREE_D`, `TWO_D_PLANAR`, and `AXISYMMETRIC` are the options available to define part dimensionality. So, these constants are available in `Part` module and `abaqusConstants` module as well. Advantage with `abaqusConstants` is it imports all the constants. However, for ex., `Part` module can import only part related constants. And hence, I think, other scripts as you mentioned works without importing `abaqusConstants`!